# Can Num2bits be used to guard against underflows?

Tags: programming, integer-overflow

In circom, `Num2bits()` from circomlib is primarily intended for converting an Integer into an array of bits.

But because of it’s optional parameter, it can be used to prevent overflows such as :

```
inp = Num2bits(120);
inp.in = (3);
```

would check that `3` is less than 120 Bits wide.

But can it be used for checking for integers underflows ? Or does because of the special way circom encode negative values compared to other languages, makes the example above would let numbers ≥(-2-2<sup>120</sup>) pass ?

Comment: At that point, I do no longer understand the difference of purposes between `Num2bits()` and `Num2bits_strict()`. But after all, the main library of circom that is circomlib is mostly undocumented.